# Cancel async parallel code

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

Given the following example:

```
private async Task<List<string>> SearchStrings(string text, ImmutableList<string> words, CancellationToken token) {
        var foundWords = new List<string>(words.Count);
        var result = await Task.Run(() =>
            Parallel.ForEach(words, (s) => {
                if (s.ToLower().Contains(text)) {
                    foundWords.Add(s);
                }
            }));
        return foundWords;
    }
```

What do i have to cancel with my token? Is it the task, the parallel execution or both? And where do i have to catch which exception?

Comment: Do you really want to support cancellation for this method? If yes, then it's the task which should be initiated with that cancellation token

Comment: This is just an example. The question is in general what i have to cancel.

Comment: edited my comment ... check again

Comment: What do you _want_ to cancel? This question isn't very clear, but is likely a duplicate of one of the numerous existing "how do I cancel my async task?" questions already on Stack Overflow. You can check the token inside the `Task.Run()` lambda, or inside the `Parallel.ForEach()` lambda; which is correct depends on what behavior you're trying to achieve. Regardless of which you pick, if you cancel by throwing an exception that will cancel the entire operation. So it comes down to how often/when you want to check for cancellation.

Comment: What i really want to cancel is the method (SearchStrings) itself. The purpose of the task here is to offload the waiting time from the UI Thread until the parallel execution has finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `CancellationToken` to the task **and** the loop as shown below:

```
private async Task<List<string>> SearchStrings(string text, ImmutableList<string> words, CancellationToken token) {
    var foundWords = new List<string>( words.Count );
    var result = await Task.Run( () =>
         Parallel.ForEach( words, new ParallelOptions { CancellationToken = token, }, ( s ) => {
             if ( s.ToLower().Contains( text ) )
             {
                 foundWords.Add( s );
             }
         } ), token );
    return foundWords;
}
```

- [`Task.Run( Action action, CancellationToken token )`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh160373(v=vs.110).aspx)

  > If cancellation is requested before the task begins execution, the task does not execute. Instead it is set to the `Canceled` state and throws a `TaskCanceledException` exception.
- [`Parallel.ForEach<TSource>( IEnumerable<TSource> source, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action<TSource> body )`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd783747(v=vs.110).aspx)

  Throws `OperationCanceledException` when the `CancellationToken` in the `parallelOptions` argument is canceled

**PS** You should use a thread safe list/collection for `foundWords`

Comment: Why do i need to cancel the loop? Is it not enough to cancel the task only?

Comment: The token passed as an argument to the task will **only** cancel the task **before the task begins execution**. Once the task is running you had to handle the cancellation within your code and that is the loop ;o)